# Julia error in assigning global variables to a tuple in global m,n = size(x);

Tags: julia

I would expect the global variables m and n get the first and second dimension size. However it seeems incorrect:

```
julia> x=rand(3,3)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.680079  0.929336  0.267358
 0.874437  0.625239  0.804478
 0.92407   0.737254  0.443433

julia> m,n = size(x);
julia> m,n
(3,3)

julia> global m,n = size(x);
julia> m,n
(3,(3,3))
```

Why is this behaviour of assigning 2 variables to a tuple different when we add the global key word?

Comment: Julia 0.6 gives a depreciation warning `Use "global m; global n=size(x)" instead.` which gives a clue how your expression gets interpreted. You can use `global (m,n) = size(x)` to get what you want.

Comment: Nice. I tried that and got an error message on 0.5 - but it's the intuitive resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to split the statement at the comma. If you just do

```
x = rand(3,3)
global m,n = size(x)
```

in a fresh session, you will see that `m` is not defined (in your example it is defined from the statement just before). `global` takes the `m` out of the assignment and assigns the result to `n`.

I think you have to

```
global m = size(x,1)
global n = size(x,2)
```